# How to introspect a Flex component before adding it to display

Tags: apache-flex, components

Suppose you have a MyView.mxml file, which is basically a Panel with
 several children (Form, FormItems, Buttons...).

Is it possible to iterate over the MyView and get all the information about
 its children (types, id ...) before it is displayed.

In my Main.mxml if I have this function

```
    public function iterateOverChildren(comp:Container):void {
        // Get the number of descriptors.
        trace("Running iterateOverChildren for " + comp.id);
        if (comp != null)
        {
        var n:int = comp.childDescriptors.length;
        for (var i:int = 0; i < n; i++) {
            var c:ComponentDescriptor = comp.childDescriptors[i];
            var d:Object = c.properties;

            // Log ids and types of objects in the Array.
            trace(c.id + " is of type " + c.type);

            // Log the properties added in the MXML tag of the object.
            for (var p:String in d) {
                trace("Property: " + p + " : " + d[p]);
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Why does this call not work ?

var myV = MyView();
 iterateOverChildren(myV);

It only works if I add a statement like
 addChild(myV);
 before the iterateOverChildren call. (But that's not what I want, I want to
 iterate the descriptions without adding it to display).

When I read this
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layoutperformance_06.html

I thought the "childDescriptors" method is independent from the life cycle, it would let me introspect the component without adding to display. What did I miss ? How do I introspect a component before displayed.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to iterate over all of MyView's children? Depending on what information you're looking for, there are multiple ways of doing it.

Comment: I have this meta-data for each item (children) in the back-end per user role. I used to bring all the meta-data but now the application has becoming larger and want to bring down only the related meta data from the back-end. I want to write something dynamic to find all these 'id's (that's my key for meta data) say from MyView before I instantiate. I know getChildren results depends on the creationPolicy, so I when I've read about childDescriptors, it looked like the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of component instantiation in Flex.

If you use the constructor in ActionScript, you get a bare metal object where nothing but construction of the object itself has been completed. In particular, this new object has not yet instantiated its child views, that's why you don't see anything when you look at the results of `getChildren()`.

If you write down your component in MXML, the MXML compiler creates ComponentDescriptors instead of "real" objects. These hold all information you specified for the object in MXML (properties, bindings, event handlers etc), and the runtime uses them to create real objects at the appropriate time. "Appropriate time" usually means "when the object is added to the display list". That's why you only see children after calling `addChild()` (technically, not immediately after calling addChild(), but only after your newly instantiated object has dispatched its creationComplete event).

Comment: Thanks Simon. I think I still not understand 100%, the usage of childDescriptors over getChildren(). 

"All containers have a childDescriptors property.
Depending on the value of the creationPolicy property, Flex immediately begins instantiating controls inside the containers or it defers their instantiation. If instantiation is deferred, you can use the properties of this Array to access the ComponentDescriptor of each component and create that object at a specified time."

Is your interpretation of the above that the descriptors are not immediately available.

Comment: The descriptors are immediately available, however only for objects created in MXML code. If you instantiate an object in ActionScript by calling the constructor as in `var myV = MyView();`, you're getting a real object which does not have childDescriptors.

Comment: Got it thanks.
If I do this
var myV = MyView(); 
myV.initialize();
iterateOverChildren(myV);

I will get the information. 
How can I make this recursive ? In my iterateIVerChildren code var c is a ComponentDescriptor. Can I find c's children ?

Comment: UIComponent.initialize() already works recursively. After calling it, you should be able to access myV's children via getChildren().

Comment: Also, reading the Flex source has helped me in the past when the documentation was unclear. It's pretty readable.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am back to square one. Running initialize() explicitly caused Runtime Errors on some of my components. I appreciate if someone can take a stab for writing the code for function displayAllTheIdsRecursively() below. (I am not lazy, I am just stuck).
var myV:MyView = new MyView();
// Below function would display the id of all UIComponents (recursive) from MyView 
displayAllTheIdsRecursively(myV);

Comment: You will probably need to wait until the initialize is finished.  So set an event handler for the initialized event (I think that's the right one) then you should be able to get to the childDescriptors.